# Rotate right border using css

Tags: html, css

I have a menu list. Now for each menu there is a right hand border.I would like to rotate that border 20deg.

Html

```
<ul class="menu">
<li>Home</li>
<li>About Us</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.menu li:after { border-right:1px solid #000; transform:rotate(20deg); }
ul.menu li{ display:inline-block; padding:0 1rem;}
```

But the above code is not working.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simpler way to do it, by just using `content: "/"`, it doesn't look all the same as border but you can get similar results by adjusting the `font-size` and `line-height` etc. And it works cross mostly all browsers.

```css
ul.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 1rem;
}
ul.menu li:after {
    content: "/";
    padding-left: 1rem;
}
ul.menu li:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
}
ul.menu li:last-child:after {
    content: "";
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About Us</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Be sure to find out if it's ok to use rem in your project - http://caniuse.com/#feat=rem

Comment: Awesome solution. Less code and superb solution. Thanks a lot. Yes I can use rem.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of border, you'll have to actually add an element after it:

CSS:

```
ul.menu li:after { content: ""; background: #000; width: 1px; height: 100%; position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; transform:rotate(20deg); }
ul.menu li{ position: relative; display:inline-block; padding:0 1rem;}
```

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/31xa0rLu/